# How can I concatenate a string to an ident in a macro derive?

Tags: rust, rust-macros

I need to create a macro derive where the name is part of the function name. *(This code does not work, it is only to show the problem)*

```
fn impl_logic(ast: &syn::DeriveInput) -> TokenStream {
    let name:&syn::Ident = &ast.ident;

    let gen = quote! {
       pub fn #name_logic() -> Arc<Mutex<UiAplicacion>> {
           ...
       }
    };

    gen.into()
}
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Based on `quote`'s [docs](https://docs.rs/quote/0.6.13/quote/macro.quote.html#constructing-identifiers), you can construct a new identifier with `syn::Ident`:

```
let fname = format!("{}_logic", name);
let varname = syn::Ident::new(&fname, ident.span());
```

and then interpolate it:

```
let gen = quote! {
   pub fn #varname() -> Arc<Mutex<UiAplicacion>> {
       ...
   }
```

Answer (score 4):

For folks arriving here later, the current preferred approach is to use `format_ident!`.

https://docs.rs/quote/latest/quote/macro.quote.html#constructing-identifiers

```rust
let varname = format_ident!("{}_logic");
```